# fsck did not recover all files - anything else to try or fresh install?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, mysql, fsck

yesterday a server of mine (debian) went into read-only mode because of problems with the main device (ext3). I contacted the hosting support and the guy told me to boot into rescue and do a fsck on the unmounted device. Lots of problems where discovered and i ended up with a messed up lost+found directory.

I tried to identify the files using "file * | grep MySQL" since i was missing a recent MySQL backup. I also did a grep searching for anything MySQL related. I noticed that the aren't any recent files in the lost+found (not even a current log).

Is there anything else to try before i re-install the server? Like an fsck option that tries harder? :)

ps: i learned that doing a fsck without doing a backup in read-only mode before was a bad idea!